# Почему не происходит сортировка

Tags: sql, mysql

Почему не происходит сортировка. Цель этого запросы - выбрать записи c users, которых нет в subscriptions

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM users
 LEFT JOIN subscriptions ON users.id = subscriptions.id_subscription
 WHERE subscriptions.id IS NULL 
 ORDER BY users.subscriptions 
 LIMIT 3
```

Мне надо сделать что-то вроде этого

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM users 
  WHERE NOT  EXISTS
  ( SELECT *
        FROM subscriptions 
        WHERE id_user = '1'
  AND id_subscription = 'users.id')
  ORDER BY users.subscriptions
  LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен, что у вас есть такой столбец: users.subscriptions.

Похоже, что это две таблицы записаны через точку. Нотация непонятна.

А что вы понимаете под сортировкой?
Какой должен быть результат?

Comment: сорри msi, я просто у себя запутался(не всем прописал users.subscriptions) из-за этого нежданный результат